# How is cake PHP different from normal PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have worked with php, writing procedural code with no concept of class and objects or MVC pattern. I want to move to OOP in php with MVC. I have heard of cake PHP and people say it is a MVC framework. What actually is it? Is it a style of programming or is there something i need to download to work with cake php. I have gone through many sites and am still not clear about it. Please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need read about it [Understanding Model-View-Controller, CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html)

As their name describe it, with an MVC framework you can separate your views, controllers and model (a shortcut to handle querys). It's a good way to work with more complex projects.

Also, have a lot of stuff (html helper, form helpers, etc) that help you to do your work more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I believe that you have to understand what is the function of framework and what does MVC framework does. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654762/what-is-an-mvc-framework-and-why-is-it-necessary-useful) is an article that maybe useful for you. It doesn't mention about cakephp but it maybe useful to understand what is MVC framework.

I will explain how does MVC works in my opinion. I have been using cakephp for a year now but I don't guarantee my explanation is the best, but I will try my best to explain it.

MVC stands for Model-View-Controller
Model is known for the database table structure. In cakephp you will defined a certain format of data or validation of data on server side.

View is known for the view of the page and normally consists of the javascript/jquery and html mark up as well as the php codes. This view will be your actual user view or simply what your users would/should see.

Controller is known for the main stage for processing data that you obtain from all the Models and passing this processed data into the view. You can create a lot of function and class to be used to processed data.

You can further read more on the cakephp website, [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html) is the link to cakephp website.

You need to download cakephp from cakephp website or from github and put it into your web server root directories, example in wamp is www folder.